# How to set up OMSA on Dell T610 with Debian 12 based OS (Proxmox VE 8.0)

Tags: debian, dell-poweredge, proxmox, dell-openmanage, debian-bookworm

Dedicated server noobie here.

I have a proxmox server on a new (to me) Dell T610. I have a couple of disks in a RAID array that I will expand soon, but for that I read that the Ctrl+R RAID BIOS is not capable of doing that and I will need OMSA on the server.

The server is running Proxmox, which is Debian based, but sadly I was unable to find a comprehensive tutorial/collection of instructions.

Can someone help me please/point me in the right direction?

Cheers!

Comment: You can use this as starting point. But from what I see OMSA is compatible with RedHat and SuSE. https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000132087/support-for-dell-emc-openmanage-server-administrator-omsa

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working on my R710 Proxmox VE 8.0.4 installation by following the instructions in the post - https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/dell-openmanage-on-proxmox-6-x.57932/post-574210.